# Firebase giving error : cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to upload a photo in firebase storage and once its uploaded a downloadURL to be printed on console. 
Photo is uploaded perfectly without any issue but in console instead of downloadURL  , undefined is printed and an error thrown which states that 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined'.

```
const file = $('#exampleInputFile').get(0).files[0]; // getting file to be uploaded 
const name = (+new Date() + '-' + file.name); // creating filename with timestamp
const task = ref.child(name).put(file, {contentType: file.type});  //setting file 

task.then( (snapshot) =>  console.log (snapshot.downloadURL))
.then(downloadURL => {
console.log(`Successfully uploaded file and got download link -
${downloadURL}`);
// once done trying to get downloadURL against this upload

})

.catch(error => {
 // Use to signal error if something goes wrong.
 console.log(`Failed to upload file and get link - ${error}`);
});
//or throw and error in console
```

Comment: `console.log` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance what about the errror i.e TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined'.

Comment: I don't know about that, because I don't see `.ref` anywhere in your code, but I don't have experience with firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
save() {
    this.storageref.child(this.file.name).put(this.file).then(snapshot => {
        let image = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
            consol.log(image);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add explanation to your code.

Comment: it worked message from failed to uploaded is now changed to successfully uploaded but download link is still undefined in console